# Screen breaks apart when sidebar has too much text in it

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So basically when I write too much text in my sidebar or change font to just a bit bigger my div order break apart when in `@media (max-width: 576px)` mode.

Tried changing `col-xs` and `col-sm` class to different sizes, changing width/padding and margin of my col/ul/li/a tho nothing seemed to help.

```css
.sidebarPic {
  background-color: #5C1916;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebarText {
  float: left !important;
  background-color: #5C1916;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.sidebarText li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 1rem !important;
}

.sidebarText a {
  margin-bottom: -6rem;
  padding-bottom: -6rem;
  font-size: 3.2vw !important;
  color: #F5A872 !important;
}

.a {
  line-height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.foxdrop {
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col sidebar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5  sidebarPic foxdrop">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="img/ornament.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7  sidebarText foxdrop">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a class="a" href="#" style="text-decoration: none">ASDASD asda asdasd </a></li>
        <li><a class="a" href="#" style="text-decoration: none">ASDASD</a></li>
        <li><a class="a" href="#" style="text-decoration: none">ASDASD</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Edit:
Was not sure if they are needed so i just left media queries out in the first version of the question.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.sidebarPic{
  display: none;
}
}
@media (max-width: 576px) {
.sidebarText a{
  font-size: 3.2vw !important; 
}
}
```

This is everything relevant to the text above, hope it helps.

I'm a beginner so so the best solution for a other problem was the `.foxdrop` class. Wrote it here just in case though I don't think it should cause a problem. Thanks for the time anyway.

Comment: where are your media queries?

Comment: @RachelGallen Just added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshots, that is called overflow (when an element is bigger than the container).

I believe one problem you are encountering is because the class .col has 15px padding to the left and right; so, as your screen scales, your responsively sized text does not quite scale in line with the container that it is in. So, you it may break at some sizes but not others.

As for why it overflows when you add letters or increase font-size.  A single word cannot wrap; so, if the browser goes past the end of the container with a single word, if will just keep going until it finishes the word. Two smaller words would line wrap instead.  You should set your font & side-bar sizes to accommodate the largest word you expect to need to display.  If one word is too big you can also hyphenate it manually to help it line break.

My personal preference is to always give side-bars a fixed width (usual ~300-350px) that becomes 100% at the responsive breakpoint.  And to just let the larger main content area resize to the screen.  That way the sidebar content stays a comfortably readable size on all screens without having to mess with vw font sizes.

Comment: I actually delete the picture when it gets to 767px of screen width, and the problem still consists. As for the text it is set to 3.2vw initially so it probably isn't that, unless I'm missing something here.  Guess i will have to fix the sidebar myself, since I'm not finding any other solutions. Thanks for the reply mister!

Comment: 3.2vw means 3.2% of the screen's width (not the column's) based on an estimated character width.  If your sidebar is only 33% of the screen, and 42% of that is image, that's only enough room for an average of 5.98 characters.  And script fonts can really mess with vw estimations because they tend to be so inconsistent with character widths compared to other fonts; so, really I'd sat 5 big letters or 7 smaller ones is your limit which is consistent with https://ibb.co/5Mq3PFB.

Comment: Also, if you keep all your horizontal margins in %, you should not need to drop your image since everything should scale exactly to the proportions of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by your 'div order break apart'? Just tried your code, everything seems to be ok the way you set it up: For tablet and larger screens, the "col-lg-5 col-md-5" and "col-lg-7 col-md-7" in your sideBarPic and sideBarText respectively will make it so (from left to right) your side bar pic takes up 5/12 units and side bar text takes up 7/12 units. For smaller screens, as expected, since you didn't specify how to handle those breakpoints, the sideBarPic and sideBarText divs become full block elements and take up the full screen, with sideBarPic at the top first, followed by sideBarText below it.

[for tablet and larger screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhC6y.png)

[for smaller-than-tablet screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpp29.png)

[for smaller-than-tablet screens; with lots of extra text added to side bar text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th1rs.png)

Comment: I guess i didn't explain clear enough, hope this pictures help a bit.
https://ibb.co/5Mq3PFB is the problem when full screen, basically the text just runs out. 
https://ibb.co/Lr4sYkS this is what happens when i resize the screen to about 576px width.
And this is how it should look like tho with bigger font: https://ibb.co/xDLRKZQ. If I give it font a bit bigger font or more text it breaks like in the 2nd picture. Hope you understand what i meant now and sorry for the misleading explanation earlier.

Comment: Btw this is what it looks like in full screeen https://ibb.co/9y2YjzT . (I set display: none ) on picture when it hits 767px.